# Calculate maximum possible Aave collateral token withdraw

Tags: aave

A user's Aave collateral tokens (aTokens) are transferrable as long as the transfer does not cause the health factor to go below `1`.

Given this condition, and ANY possible configuration of supplied collateral (one token, many tokens), I want to calculate the maximum possible amount that is transferrable for any given token.
For example, if I have 1 ETH supplied, 500 USDC supplied, and 1000 DAI borrowed, how do I calculate how much aEthWETH I am able to transfer?

I've noticed that the Aave app calculates value this when you try to withdraw (the `max` button), I am simply wondering how this calculation is done.

Thanks.